# In flutter source code, why Dart Generics can write code like this?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter source code there is a Mixin named ContainerRenderObjectMixin(in object.dart file),it use Generics makes me confused?
Like this:

```
class ParentData {
  ...
}

abstract class RenderObject {
  ParentData parentData;
  ...
}

mixin ContainerParentDataMixin<ChildType extends RenderObject> on ParentData {
  ...
}

mixin ContainerRenderObjectMixin<ChildType extends RenderObject, ParentDataType extends ContainerParentDataMixin<ChildType>> on RenderObject {
  bool _debugUltimatePreviousSiblingOf(ChildType child, { ChildType equals }) {
    ParentDataType childParentData = child.parentData;
    while (childParentData.previousSibling != null) {
      assert(childParentData.previousSibling != child);
      child = childParentData.previousSibling;
      childParentData = child.parentData;
    }
    return child == equals;
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't know how can the dart confirm this code[ParentDataType childParentData = child.parentData], why parentData's Type is ParentDataType? I think parentData's Type can be any subclass of ParentData.

I'm not familiar with Dart can anyone tell me why this code not error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "type safe", if that's what you're thinking.
They are casting `child.parentData` from `ParentData` to `ParentDataType`.

But this won't cause problems because `child.parentData` is "guaranteed`to be`ParentDataType` in the scope of that code.

It is part of the contract of `ContainerRenderObjectMixin` that `child.parentData` is a `ParentDataType`.

Comment: How did Dart promise [It is part of the contract of ContainerRenderObjectMixin that child.parentData is a ParentDataType.], can you describe it more concretely? Is it means when write the subclass of RenderObject with ContainerRenderObjectMixin, the subclass must guarantee child.parentData is a ParentDataType?

Comment: Dart doesn't guarantee anything. It's like you said, subclass must respect that.